# Play Local m3u8 files in Android using NanoHttpd

Tags: android, android-videoview, m3u8, nanohttpd

I need to play local m3u8 file which is stored on device SD card. From my Google search I came to know that I should use nanoHttpd server but not able to find and samples or examples.
Please suggest me any sample codes or examples.